It is with deep regret that we announce his death

It is with deep regret that we announce his death.

Does the verb 'is' mean 'to exist' or 'a linking verb' like "It is of importance that we should save our energy."?

Yes, it just connects and doesn't announce the existence of "it" at all. The tone to set here is a serious one, so the sentence starts with formality.

It is [etc.] is used to describe things or situations. But it is of importance is not idiomatic. It is important that we etc.

In English, we regret mistakes and experience sorrow at the death of a person.  It is with great sorrow that we etc. Not regret. –


It is with [emotion phrase] that we [verb phrase announcing an event].

This is a formulaic, oratorical structure used with birth announcements, wedding invitations, death notices, company hires, etc.  The form is a "heightened" version of the simple statement of fact, which would sound anti-climactic:

We [verb phrase]  with [emotion phrase].


The format is <subject><verb><prepositional phrase><subordinate clause>, where everything after the verb is part of the predicate nominative, or modifying it.

It is <with hope for peace><that the nations meet.>
It was <with joy><that she won.>
It will be <with sadness><that we leave.>

And, from that citation, "It was she who took care of me."

Your first example may be a bit confusing. To be parallel with the OP’s sentence (and your other two examples), it must mean that as the parties conclude negotiating the treaty, they will be full of hope. The confusion may arise if readers are influenced by the similarity to the frequently occurring sentence-initial hopefully, which in most such uses is intended to convey “It is hoped that.” And It is hoped that the treaty will be concluded is not parallel to the OP’s sentence.
